# More equivalent conditions for meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f  $ be holomorphic on $D_r(a)\setminus \{a\}$. I want to show that $f$ is meromorphic on $D_r(a)$ if and only if there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ in $D_r(a)$ such that

1. Either $f$ is bounded on $U\setminus\{a\}$
2. Or, $|f(z)| \to \infty $ as $z\to a$

Definition of meromorphic that I am using:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\Omega \setminus \{z_1, \ldots z_n\}$. Then
> $f$ is meromorphic on $\Omega$, if for each $z_i$, $\exists D_p(z_i)$
> inside $\Omega$ such that $g, h$ are holomorphic on $D_p(z_i)$ and $h$
> is not identically zero and $\frac{g}{h} = f$ on $ D_p(z_i)\setminus\{z_i\}$

I also now know the following result:

> Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$ and $f(z) =
>  \sum\limits_{n\in Z}c_n (z-a)^n$ be its unique Laurent series on
> $D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$ Then, $f$ is meromorphic if
> and only if $\exists N_0 \geq 0$ such that $c_n = 0\; \forall n < -N_0$

I somehow want to use this result to solve the question on top.

If I assume $f$ to be meromorphic, then I get

$f(z) = \sum_{n\geq -N_0}c_n(z-z_0)^n$

I really can't see how to proceed from here. Help will be appreciated.

--

My attempt for 1.

For the case 1. by Riemann's Extension theorem, $a$ will be removable singularity and $f$ will be extended to a holomorphic functions on $D_r(a)$, call it $F$. Now $F$ will have taylor series which will agree with $f$ on $D_r(a) \setminus\{a\}$. By uniqueness, $c_n= 0\; \forall n < 0$. So by the result that I mentioned below definition, we would conclude that $f$ is meromorphic on $D_r(a)$

Would this be correct argument for 1.?

My attempt for case 2. This I am not really sure of

This means that $\frac1{f}$ will be bounded on some punctured neighbourhood of $a$, call it, $U\setminus \{a\}$. So by 1., $\frac{1}{f}$ will be meromorphic ? How can I get $f$ to be meromorphic from this?

Also, so far I could only discuss the reverse implication part. I am unable to think of a way to argue for the forward implication.

Comment: Hint: in case 2, $1/f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Riemann's theorem on removable singularities?

Comment: @MartinR Yes I know that theorem.

Comment: So in case (1) you can conclude that $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $U$. Do you see how that implies that $f$ is meromorphic in $D_r(a)$? – In case (2) consider $1/f$ instead of $f$, as Greg suggested.

Comment: @MartinR thank you, I will think more about it and complete the proof in my post.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinR It is less a theorem than a basic lemma of that holomorphic functions are analytic. If $f$ is bounded at the isolated point then $(z-a)^2 f(z)$ is holomorphic thus analytic. If $f(a)=\infty$ then $(z-a)^2 /f(z)$ is holomorphic thus analytic around $a$, it has a zero of order $n>2$ so that $(z-a)^{n-2} f(z)$ is analytic.

Comment: @reuns: I called it “Riemann's theorem” because that is what it is called [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem), so other people might know it under that name. But you are of course correct, I am familiar with that argument.

Comment: @MartinR can you please check my arguments for the two cases.